# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm building a website using PHP & Ajax. 
I can't fetch data. 
I constantly get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 "
However, the data is sent to my database successfully and there're no errors in the network.

Ajax file:

```
document.getElementById("btnSendPrivateMessage").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let chatId = this.dataset.chatid;
    let text = document.querySelector('#privateMessageText').value;

    console.log(chatId);
    console.log(text);


    //sent to DB
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("text_message", text);
    formData.append("chat_id", chatId);

    fetch("ajax/saveMessage.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Success:", result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    });
});
```

PHP file with json_encode

```
<?php 
require("../classes/Db.class.php");
require("../classes/ChatPrivateMessage.class.php");
require("../datetime.php");
session_start();  

if(!empty($_POST)){
    header("Content-type: application/json");

    $m = new ChatPrivateMessage();

    $m->setChatId($_POST['chat_id']);
    $m->setText($_POST['text_message']);
    $m->setUser1($_SESSION['user_id']);
    $m->setDate(getTime());

    $textM = htmlspecialchars($m->getText()) ;


    $m->saveMessage();

    $response = [
        "status" => "success",
        "body" => $textM,
        "message" => "something"
    ];

    header("Content-type:application/json"); 

    echo json_encode($response);
};  
?>
```

Comment: What's the response body?

Comment: Please check https://www.kevinleary.net/syntax-error-unexpected-token-json-position-0/

Comment: you are probably receiving some html buffered as the result of some kind of php error being reported.  Observe the body (as per @kevmo314's suggestion) and you will get a hing of the underlying issue.

Comment: @kevmo314 responde budy is not the problem even if i but string into this i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like server doesn't respond with JSON but with HTML (maybe it responds with HTML page describing the error occurred). Check what the backend response is exactly.

Comment: And how to check background response?

Comment: Try to console.log ‘response’ before calling response.json() function which is possibly crashing.

Comment: it gives response.text() back and then Success is undefined, but it has a problem with response.json(). I don't know how to fix it none of Google tricks works.

Answer (score 0):

for friends who want to check up-to-date, if there is any **HTML code** information on the page where you are processing the code, it reads the information sent from ajax but returns an error. Therefore, there should not be any HTML code on the processed page. Otherwise you will get an error. Note that the page is purely php codes. This way my problem was fixed. It is very simple and requires attention.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).